# Registering XPCOM in firefox. Unknown CID

Tags: c++, firefox, xpcom

I'm having difficulties registering an example XPCOM component into firefox from this example here: http://www.iosart.com/firefox/xpcom/
I'm trying this on Firefox 3.6. After successfully building and transferring the XPT and library into the components folder in firefox, and following what instructions are applicable, I'm unable to get the components successfully registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [first bullet point here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/firefox_3.6_for_developers#Miscellaneous).  This method of adding components to Firefox no longer works in Firefox 3.6.

Comment: Sorry for not updating the question, but I found out already that they stopped supported extending javascript through XPCOM. But will this work through installing as a standard XPI package? I'll try it.

Comment: "Extending JavaScript through XPCOM" is rather vague and I'm not really sure what you are asking.  For that matter, that's a totally different question than this one.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create an unrestricted AJAX alternative interface, so when I need to do cross domain stuff, I can do it without having to move my files to accommodate domain policies. Well there are other advantages at that too.